# How to track the password-store in git

Tags: git, gnupg, password-management

I have started using `pass`, which creates a `.password-store` directory, with some `.gpg` files. Strangely enough:

```
» git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Right after creating a new entry, which is in the tree:

```
» tree 
.
└── flights
    └── vueling.gpg
```

My `.gitignore` has nothing special:

```
» cat .gitignore 
*~
```

Why is `git` not seeing this `.gpg` file? How can I track it?

Forcing it does nothing:

```
» git add -f flights/
» git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, it seems `pass` detects that the password store is a git repository and auto-commits the newly added password.